# How to find the two closest values to an argument in a sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to write a code which locates the two closest numbers to a given argument without using any modules. Below is what I have at the moment.

```
 list1 = (1,3,5,8,12)
 x = 9
 for value in list1:         
     point = list1[x - 1], list1[x + 1]
```

expected output is `[8,12]`

Comment: Please add a minimal and verifiable example to your question plus your expected outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sorted squared dist-list to achieve it. By calculating a difference and sqaring it you get rid of negative distances. Things that are close to the target value, i.e.

```
 9 - x =  0 ==> squared 0
10 - x =  1 ==> squared 1
 8 - x = -1 ==> squared 1
12 - x =  3 ==> squared 9  etc.
```

stay close, things far away get even farer away.

```
# your "list" was a tuple - make it a list
data = [1,3,5,8,12]
x = 9

# calculate the difference between each value and your target value x
diffs = [t-x for t in data]  
print(diffs)

# sort all diffs by the squared difference 
diffsSorted = sorted([t-x for t in data], key = lambda x:x**2) 
print(diffsSorted)

# take the lowes 2 of them
diffVals = diffsSorted[0:2]
print(diffVals)

# add x on top again
values = [t + x for t in diffVals]

print(values)


# Harder to understand, but you could reduce it into a oneliner: 
allInOne=[k+x for k in sorted([t-x for t in data], key = lambda x:x**2)][:2]
print(allInOne)
```

Output:

```
[-8, -6, -4, -1, 3]  # difference between x and each number in data 
                     # [64, 36, 16, 1, 9] are the squared distances   
[-1, 3, -4, -6, -8]  # sorted differences
[-1, 3]              # first 2 - just add x back
[8, 12]              # result by stepwise
[8, 12]              # result allInOne
```

Intermediate steps (not printed):

```
[64, 36, 16, 1, 9]   # squared differences - we use that as key to 
                     # sort  [-8, -6, -4, -1, 3] into [-1, 3, -4, -6, -8]
```

---

Some measurements comparing heapq and list-approach (changing to abs() instead of squared):

```
import timeit

setup = """ 
import random

random.seed(42)
rnd = random.choices(range(1,100),k={})

import heapq

x = 42
n = 5 """

h = "fit = heapq.nsmallest(n, rnd, key = lambda L: abs(x - L))"
l = "allInOne=[k+x for k in sorted([t-x for t in rnd], key = lambda x:abs(x))][:n]"


rt = {}
for k in range(1,6):
    s = setup.format(10**k)

    rt[10**k] = (timeit.timeit(l,setup=s,number=1000),timeit.timeit(h,setup=s,number=1000))

print(rt)
```

Output:

```
#   rnd-size      list approch             heapq
{
        10: (  0.06346651086960813, 0.11704596144812314), 
       100: (  0.5278085906813885,  0.8281634763797711), 
      1000: (  5.032436315978541,   7.462741343986483), 
     10000: ( 54.45165343575938,   79.96112521267483), 
    100000: (577.708372381287,    835.539905495399)
}
```

list is always faster then heapq, heapq is (especially for bigger lists) far better space-coplexity wise.

Comment: Seems an ideal case for using a heapq here especially given the two closest matches, eg: `heapq.nsmallest(2, data, lambda L: abs(9 - L))` - that way you're only retaining the two closest at any one time and applying the key only once without having to sort the entire sequence after decorating it. (oh and congrats on 10k!)

Comment: There's a trade off in speed (it's slower) vs space (uses far less)... so - while it's not necessarily obviously better - it's probably an option worth noting.

Comment: @JonClements changing x**2 to abs(x) is a nice touch I did not think about. I ran some sizes through timeit - heapq is slower by about 50% - but memorizing only 5 values instead of 100k for big lists is huge - so thanks for the comment & the grats

Comment: Just to note... your `key = lambda x:abs(x)` has a level of calling you don't need... you can just use `key=abs` there... Probably not the most massive of speedups in the weird, but one less unnecessary overhead :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
t= [abs(i-x) for i in list1]
sorted_list = sorted(enumerate(t), key=lambda i:i[1])
(list1[sorted_list[0][0]], (list1[sorted_list[1][0]]))
```

It returns a tuple of your desired values `(8, 12)`

Comment: abs() instead of (i-x)**2 ... nice +1